# Why do I need an "object reference" to access UnityEngine.Transform.Translate?

Tags: unity

Why am I getting this error?

> error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member 'UnityEngine.Transform.Translate(UnityEngine.Vector3)'

---

This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class vectr : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() 
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            Transform.Translate(Vector3.Forward * variable * Time, deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            Transform.Translate(Vector3.Backward * variable * Time, deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            Transform.Rotate(Vector3.Right * variable * Time, deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            Transform.Rotate(Vector3.Left * variable * Time, deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are accessing a non-initialized object, that is not static.  Transform.   use transform instead.

Comment: Asks a question about a game engine related error code "This is off topic!" cracks me up this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Type vs Instance

Consider the following code:

```
float myFloat = 5f;
Transform myTransform = gameObject.transform;
```

You would say that the value of `myFloat` was 5; you *would not* say that the value of `float` was 5. Why is that? `myFloat` is the name I have given to the *instance* of `float` that I then set to `5`. `float` is the *type* I am using, `myFloat` is a reference to the *instance* of that type.

In the same way, `UnityEngine.Transform` is a *type*. It is a structure, *like* a `float` but with greater complexity. If we reference `UnityEngine.Transform`, we reference the *type*, but we do not reference any particular *instance* of that type. We can access `static` fields and methods, but that is about it.

When used in the above example, you need an *object reference* to tell us *what* transform you mean to reference. In this case, I think it is safe to assume that you mean to reference the transform of the game object holding that particular script, which brings us to the next comparison.

---

#### `Transform` vs `transform`

In case you have not noticed, so far, you have a `UnityEngine.Transform` and a `UnityEngine.GameObject.transform`. Given that we usually have `using UnityEngine` at the top of our code, we usually reference these as `Transform` and `GameObject.transform`.

`Transform` represents a common component; one that is present on just about every game object. As a result, the `GameObject` class already has a field that references its specific `Transform` component. The *instance* of the `Transform` *type* you want to be referencing, when you intend to move that object.

```
void Update() 
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.Forward * variable * Time, deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        transform.Translate(Vector3.Backward * variable * Time, deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.Right * variable * Time, deltaTime);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.Left * variable * Time, deltaTime);
    }
}
```

---

#### What do we do if we do not immediately have a local reference?

This is not *usually* the case. With *other* components, you are required to create a reference to them, first. This would look something like this:

```
Transform transform;
Rigidbody rigidbody;

void Start()
{
    transform = GetComponent<Transform>();
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void Update()
{
    if(rigidbody != null)
    {
        // this object did have a rigidbody; we can reference it here, 
        // without risk of a null reference exception. Most non-transform 
        // components should be treated in this manner. You should also 
        // note that objects may have a RectTransform, not a Transform.
    }
}
```

---

#### Further Observation

- You will notice that the *type* keyword starts with a capital letter, while the *reference* name does not. You can see this, especially, the above example. This is common practice, and providing you follow it, gives you a good hint at whether the name points to a *type* or an *instance reference*. `Transform` is the type, `transform` is the object reference.
- You will also notice that most compilers colour the *type* keyword. In the above examples, `Transform` should colour in light or dark blue. This is the same default colour as *Visual Basic* and *MonoDevelop*, to of the most popular compilers for Unity. Colour coding usually implies a specific *keyword*, and will never point to a specific instance, such as the instance of object you intend to reference.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
void Update() {
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
{
    transform.Translate(Vector3.Forward * variable * Time, deltaTime);
}
```

Transform is the name of the class and transform gives you the instance to the Transform of your object. Using 'transform' lets you access the transform component of your gameobject to which the script is attached to. Hope that helps :)